# Can't get website image

Tags: phantomjs, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using PhantomJS to capture an image of a website built using Polymer. Here is my `capture.js` file:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://www.gosizzle.io/token/recruiting/957e73c45b55129b1a', function() {
  page.render('test1.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

However when I run

```
phantomjs capture.js
```

my `test1.png` only contains the footer of the website:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you need to wait (`setTimeout`) a little.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Nope, that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.